# Shopify Multiple Shipping Addresses

Tags: shopify

Does anyone know if there's a way to integrate multiple shipping addresses into a Shopify website? Currently they only support one address per order. The website I'm currently working on is a gift shop so needs to allow customer the option to ship each item to a different address.

So far the only workaround I've come up with is to add shipping address fields as line item properties on the product page and disable/hide shipping fields in the checkout area. However, the concern then becomes sales tax. For this website any items shipped Washington State are subject to tax. So, I either need find a way to integrate multiple shipping addresses into the checkout or figure out how to add some sort of javascript/jQuery to calculate Washington State taxes on the product page and have it included in the product price when added to cart.

Any ideas about how to make this work would be appreciated, whether it's multiple shipping addresses or a product page tax calculation.